# AngularJs, Passing optional parameters to the URL based on user input

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngroute

I am trying to consume my ASP.NET Web API using AngularJs. The problem is that i want to pass optional parameters to the url based on the user input(2 Html Text Boxes) but i don't know how.
This is my ASP.NET Web API Controller

```
[Route("api/JobShow/{keyword}/{location}")]    
public class JobShowController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public PageResult<sp_JobSearch_Result> Get(ODataQueryOptions<sp_JobSearch_Result> options, string keyword = null, string location = null)
    {
        ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings()
        {
            PageSize = 20
        };

        JobWindow obj = new JobWindow();
        IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(obj.showJobs(keyword, location).AsQueryable(), settings);
        return new PageResult<sp_JobSearch_Result>(
           results as IEnumerable<sp_JobSearch_Result>,
           Request.GetNextPageLink(),
           Request.GetInlineCount());
    }
}
```

And this is my AngularJS controller

```
angular.module('JobSearch.SiteController', []).controller('JobSearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/api/JobShow').success(function (data) {
    $scope.model = data;
});
}]);
```

Example of the url then would be .../api/JobShow/Java/Toronto. Thank you all.

Comment: Is the optional parameters you were talking about is the path parameters `keyword` and `location` ?

Comment: Yes they are. I am showing it in the attribute route on my API Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) !

You first need to include ng-resource

> ```
> <script src="angular.js">
> <script src="angular-resource.js">
> ```

You can get it via Bower or CDN, or whichever way you got AngularJS.

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label>Keyword: <input type="text" ng-model="keyword" /></label>
    <label>Location: <input type="text" ng-model="location" /></label>
    <button ng-click="getJobShowPage(keyword, location)">Search</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Controller**:

```
angular
  .module('MyApp', ['ngResource']) // Include the ngResource module here

  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource){

  // Create the $resource
  var JobShowPage = $resource('/api/JobShow/:keyword/:location', {keyword: "@keyword", location: "@location"})

  // Make a scope function to use the resource properly
  $scope.getJobShowPage = function(keyword, location) {
    var parameters = {};
    if (keyword) {
      parameters["keyword"] = keyword;
      if (location) {
        parameters["location"] = location;
      }
    }
    return JobShowPage.get(parameters);
  };


}]);
```

**Input/Outputs**:

When the user enters nothing and clicks 'Search', the HTTP request would be `/api/JobShow`

If only the `keyword` is entered, the HTTP request would be `/api/JobShow/{{keyword}}`

If both the `keyword` and `location` is entered, the HTTP request would be `/api/JobShow/{{keyword}}/{{location}}`

If only the `location` is entered (no keyword), the HTTP request would be the vanilla one `/api/JobShow`

You can consume the return value of the $resource query like a promise:

```
JobShowPage.get(parameters).$promise.then(function(response){
  // Do Stuff
  $scope.model = response.data;
});
```

by callbacks:

```
JobShowPage.get(parameters, function(err, response){
  // Do Stuff
  $scope.model = response.data;
});
```

Or auto unwrap it:

```
// This works, but it's asynchronous
// Useful if consuming directly from the Angular Template
$scope.model = JobShowPage.get(parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I'm going to assume you have 2 textboxes and a search button, and when the search button is pressed, you want to call your GET endpoint. For this scenario, what you'll want to do is bind the textbox inputs to your scope and bind the search button using ng-click to a function in your scope that will call your endpoint. It might look something like this:

controller

```
angular.module('JobSearch.SiteController', [])
.controller('JobSearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getResults= getResults;

    function getResults() {
        $http.get('/api/JobShow/' + $scope.keyword + '/' + $scope.location).success(function (data) {
            $scope.model = data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

html

```
<div ng-controller="JobSearchCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="keyword">
    <input type="text" ng-model="location">
    <button type="button" ng-click="getResults()">Search</button>
</div>
```